# How can I convert ISCII encoding to unicode for Gujarati language in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

I have some Gujarati string but its in ISCII encoding, so python throughing error (SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal).

```py
string = TFH[TZDF\ I]GF.8[0 G[Xg;
```

```
line 1
    string = TFH[TZDF\ I]GF.8[0 G[Xg;
                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I was tried byte encoding too, but its not giving output like ISCII encoding.

I am trying this to make ISCII into unicode for Gujarati language.
I have ISCII based font and character map data also.

ISCII input string: TFH[TZDF\ I]GF.8[0 G[Xg;
Desired unicode output: તાજેતરમાં યુનાઇટેડ નેશન્સ (Typed using gujarati phonetic keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to write the string literal, for me, just writing `print("તાજેતરમાં યુનાઇટેડ નેશન્સ")` worked.
Or you could write:

```
characters = [2724, 2750, 2716, 2759, 2724, 2736, 2734, 2750, 2690, 32, 2735, 2753, 2728, 2750, 2695, 2719, 2759, 2721, 32, 2728, 2759, 2742, 2728, 2765, 2744]
string = str()
for c in characters:
        string += chr(c)
```

Maybe you have a look at this conversion script:
https://gist.github.com/pathumego/81672787807c23f19518c622d9e7ebb8

Comment: Use `string = ''.join([chr(c) for c in characters])` instead of your 3-line jerky code snippet?

Comment: Yes, that would be more pythonic. I don't know if the oneliner would create all chr(c) before joining them, which would need more memory, that's why I don't have written that.